# How make custom link attribute apply to one element?

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently making my own elements and attributes in HTML and I have switched the `href` tag to the `loc` attribute and have attached it to three different `<navlink>` tags. I have set it up so when you click on the `<navlink>` it goes to the `loc` destination, however, the `loc` of the first `<navlink>` determines where all of the links go on the page, which is not what I wanted. I was wondering if I could have a different link for each `navlink` using the `loc` attribute?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
<body>

    <!--Navbar-->
    <navbar>
        <navlinks>

            <navlink loc="https://www.apple.com">Home</navlink>
            <navlink loc="https://www.apple.com">About</navlink>
            <navlink loc="https://www.microsoft.com">Contact</navlink>

        </navlinks>
    </navbar>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="style.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my jQuery:

```
var navlink_loc = $("navlink").attr("loc");
$('navlink').click(function(){
  $(location).attr('href', navlink_loc);
});
```

Is there a way to make it that each `<navlink>` has the `loc` attribute but goes to its specified link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the link using `$(this)` in jQuery like below. `$(this)` makes the selector the exact text you clicked on.

```js
var navlink_loc;
$('navlink').click(function() {
  navlink_loc = $(this).attr("loc");
  $(location).attr('href', navlink_loc);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--Navbar-->
  <navbar>
    <navlinks>

      <navlink loc="https://www.apple.com">Home</navlink>
      <navlink loc="https://www.apple.com">About</navlink>
      <navlink loc="https://www.microsoft.com">Contact</navlink>

    </navlinks>
  </navbar>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="style.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem